# Changing the size of an element relative to itself

Tags: css, html

I want to change the change the size of an HTML element say div relative to itself

```
 <div class="visual-cue" style="height:100px ;width:100px">
 </div>
```

Now in the CSS I want to do something like this

```
 .visual-cue:hover{
      /* change the height to 90% of current height and same for width
      */
  }
```

I would like to do it without javascript. Right now using 
         width:90%

does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean 90% of the screen (viewport), you can use `vw` as a unit:

```css
.visual-cue {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.visual-cue:hover {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
}

.smoothsize {
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="visual-cue smoothsize">X
 </div>
```

Or, if you meant 90% of its original size, use `transform: scale(0.9)`:

```css
.visual-cue {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.visual-cue:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.smoothsize{
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="visual-cue smoothsize">X
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks that really saved my life and i meant relative to itself.

Answer (score 1):

could use:

```
  .visual-cue:hover{
    transform:scale(0.9,0.9)
   }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/0xr7c0qs/)